# Android 2.1 Device's won't rotate landscape left

Tags: java, android

This problem has been tested on HTC Hero and Samsung Moment.  The app rotates to landscape right (turn phone to the right) and back to portrait, but will not rotate to landscape left (turn phone to left).  This only happens on 2.1 devices.  Any idea why and how to fix?

Comment: Are you using [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29), or just letting the app restart?

Comment: onConfigChanged - none of my activities call onCreate on rotation

Comment: Do any standard apps on those devices rotate left? If not, I'd say it's a device limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the phone simply does not support it, in which case you cannot do anything from a simple application.... at least nothing easily. If you are creating a game, which uses a custom view for rendering, what you could do is listen to sensor events yourself, and rotate the rendering (and touch event coordinates).